# Update Single Bar in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a bar graph using matplotlib and according to a condition in my code I need to change the color of one of the bar. Is it possible to change the color of a single bar in the plot without plotting a new bar graph, because that would increase the complexity ?

Related: [how to change the color of a single bar if condition is True matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832809/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-if-condition-is-true-matplotlib)

Comment: another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903750/vary-the-color-of-each-bar-in-bargraph-using-particular-value

Comment: It does not specify what I asked for ? I have already plotted the graph and want to change the color of one bar. (Plotting the graph again with updated colors will be quite complex)

Comment: Did you try anything? bar.set_color(..) for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) returns a [`matplotlib.container.BarContainer`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/container_api.html#matplotlib.container.BarContainer), in which the individual bars are stored as [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) objects. Given that

> The container can be treated as a tuple of the patches themselves. Additionally, you can access these and further parameters by the attributes

You can extract the patch for the specific bar or bars you want and change its color. An example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)
bars = plt.bar(x, x)
bars[2].set_color('orange')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the code to make it consistent with the text you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @kunal I’m glad this solution worked for you. Be sure to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer so the question is marked as such for future users.