# How can I change a single bar in a bar plot to a different colour?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, jupyter

I have a dataframe that looks as follows

| ACQUISITION_CHANNEL | RIDER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Organic | 2735 |
| Referral | 1216 |
| Digital | 751 |
| Offline | 296 |
| Unknown | 108 |
| Job Platforms | 67 |

And I am making a bar plot as below using:

```
channel_rider_count.plot(kind='bar', 
                         legend=None)

plt.title('Count of Riders by Acquisition Channel')
plt.xlabel('Acquisition Channel')
plt.ylabel('Count')
```

How can I change the colour of the 'Referral' bar but leave the others the same?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347895/2827397) solve your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Single Bar in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347557/update-single-bar-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = ['b','r','b','b','b','b','b']

channel_rider_count.plot(kind='bar', 
                         legend=None, 
                         color=colors)

plt.title('Count of Riders by Acquisition Channel')
plt.xlabel('Acquisition Channel')
plt.ylabel('Count')
```