# Change color of specific bar in matplotlib barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to change the color of a bar in matplotlib's grouped barplot if it meets a certain condition. I'm plotting two bars for each `species` - one for `today` and one for `avg`, where `avg` contains `yerr` errorbars that show the 10th and 90th percentile values.

Now I want the `avg` bar to be green if `today`'s `length` value > 10th percentile, and red if `today`'s `length` value < 10th percentile.

I tried the solutions in these posts

- [how to change the color of a single bar if condition is True matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832809/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-if-condition-is-true-matplotlib)
- [Update Single Bar in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347557/update-single-bar-in-matplotlib)

but the bars are always green.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = pd.DataFrame(data={'length': [40,35,34,40,36,39,38,44,40,39,35,46],
                       'species': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
                       'type': ['today','avg','10pc','90pc','today','avg','10pc','90pc','today','avg','10pc','90pc']
                      },
                )
z['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-09-20')
z.set_index('Date',inplace=True)

z0 = z.loc[(z.type=='today') | (z.type=='avg')] # average length and today's length
z1 = z.loc[(z.type=='10pc') | (z.type=='90pc')] # 10th and 90th percentile

z2 = []
for n in z.species.unique().tolist():
    dz = z.loc[(z.species==n) & (z.type=='today'),'length'].values[0] - z.loc[(z.species==n) & (z.type=='10pc'),'length'].values[0]
    if dw>0:
        z2.append(1)
    else:
        z2.append(0)

errors = z1.pivot_table(columns=[z1.index,'species'],index='type',values=['length']).values
avgs = z0.length[z0.type=='avg'].values
bars = np.stack((np.absolute(errors-avgs), np.zeros([2,z1.species.unique().size])), axis=0)

col = ['pink']
for k in z2:
    if k==1:
        col.append('g') # length within 10% bounds = green
    else:
        col.append('r') # length outside 10% bounds = red

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
z0.pivot(index='species', columns='type', values='length').plot(kind='bar', yerr=bars, ax=ax, color=col, capsize=0)
ax.set_title(z0.index[0].strftime('%d %b %Y'), fontsize=16)
ax.set_xlabel('species', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('length (cm)', fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to overwrite the colors after creating the plot. First you need to change the line that initialize `col` with

```
col = ['pink']*z['species'].nunique()
```

to get the numbers of avg bars, then the same for loop to add g or r depending on your case. Finally, change this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
z0.pivot(index='species', columns='type', values='length')\
  .plot(kind='bar', yerr=bars, ax=ax, 
        color=['pink','g'], capsize=0) # here use only pink and g
# here overwrite the colors 
for p, c in zip(ax.patches, col):
    p.set_color(c)
ax.set_title...
```

Note that the legend for today is green even if you have a red bar, could be confusing.

Here is the full working example, adding the red entry in the legend thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551701/9274732)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches # import this extra

z = pd.DataFrame(data={'length': [40,35,34,40,36,39,38,44,40,39,35,46],
                       'species': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
                       'type': ['today','avg','10pc','90pc','today','avg','10pc','90pc','today','avg','10pc','90pc']
                      },
                )
z['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-09-20')
z.set_index('Date',inplace=True)

z0 = z.loc[(z.type=='today') | (z.type=='avg')] # average length and today's length
z1 = z.loc[(z.type=='10pc') | (z.type=='90pc')] # 10th and 90th percentile

z2 = []
for n in z.species.unique().tolist():
    dz = z.loc[(z.species==n) & (z.type=='today'),'length'].values[0] - z.loc[(z.species==n) & (z.type=='10pc'),'length'].values[0]
    if dz>0:
        z2.append(1)
    else:
        z2.append(0)

errors = z1.pivot_table(columns=[z1.index,'species'],index='type',values=['length']).values
avgs = z0.length[z0.type=='avg'].values
bars = np.stack((np.absolute(errors-avgs), np.zeros([2,z1.species.unique().size])), axis=0)

col = ['pink']*z['species'].nunique()
for k in z2:
    if k==1:
        col.append('g') # length within 10% bounds = green
    else:
        col.append('r') # length outside 10% bounds = red
print(col)
# ['pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'g', 'r', 'g']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
z0.pivot(index='species', columns='type', values='length').plot(kind='bar', yerr=bars, ax=ax, color=['pink','g'], capsize=0)
for p, c in zip(ax.patches, col):
    p.set_color(c)
ax.set_title(z0.index[0].strftime('%d %b %Y'), fontsize=16)
ax.set_xlabel('species', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('length (cm)', fontsize=14)

handles = None
labels = None

if 0 in z2: ## add the entry on the legend only when there is red bar
    # where some data has already been plotted to ax
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    # manually define a new patch 
    patch = mpatches.Patch(color='r', label='today')
    # handles is a list, so append manual patch
    handles.append(patch) 
    # plot the legend
    plt.legend(handles=handles)
else:
    # plot the legend when there isn't red bar
    plt.legend(handles=handles)

plt.show()
```

and I get the red bar
[image]

Comment: the bar is still green

Comment: @MedullaOblongata see edit, added the extra color in the legend, and I do get red for the bar

Comment: thanks, this is great - I added an `if/else` statement in your code so that the legend doesn't contain a red entry when all the `today` bars are green

Comment: @MedullaOblongata you don't really need the `else` as by default the legend would be only with green and not the red, but good idea :)